# Implementing 2 bootstrap carousels on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Despite giving both carousels unique IDs, the second carousel on my page isn't functioning correctly for some reason.

For example, the second carousel's left and right arrows will do this odd thing where it just repositions itself. Also I have small grey area above the second carousel (I'm assuming some kind of height issue in the css).

I wanted to use this second carousel as a "photos gallery" carousel. Can anyone help?

https://jsfiddle.net/mrdat/nv7rsgpg/3/

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<style>

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }

.vcenter {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.v-center {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:40%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    left:15%;
}    

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Start Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#top" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <header>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/cats" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/abstract" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/transportation" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>


    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>

            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Services -->
    <!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
    <section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h2>Our Services</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Callout -->
    <aside class="callout">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Vertically Centered Text</h1>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h2>Our Work</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-3.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-4.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">View More Items</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Call to Action -->
    <aside class="call-to-action bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Click Me!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Map -->
    <section id="contact" class="map">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        <br />
        <small>
            <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
        </small>
        </iframe>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h4><strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <p>3481 Melrose Place<br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (123) 456-7890</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>  <a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just need to add one more condition/filtering in your `js` click functionality for `a` with `href="#myCarousel2"` and that works perfectly!!

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nv7rsgpg/7/)**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel]):not([href="#myCarousel2])"').click(function() {                               
                                                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^Add this      

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was easier than I thought.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data-target instead of href on the control buttons.

Like this:

```
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="" data-target="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why?